# Convert any string to timezone date and display in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the date (`String`) in different formats from the API service.
The date `String` maybe like `"2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"` or `"July 30, 2020"` or any other format.

Now I need to convert that `String` to device timezone and based on the timezone country, the date and time should display accordingly on the UI.

I tried the below:

```
    val today = LocalDate.now()
println("localdate today " + today)

val formattedToday = today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL))
println("formatted today" + formattedToday)
```

But could anyone tell how to convert the `String` that is coming from API to device timezone format in android kotlin?

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The date `String` maybe like `"2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"` or `"July 30, 2020"` or any other format.

... is going to cause a lot of work. You will have to take care of a multitude of possible formats. The input you are receiving may be a date plus time plus zone / offest (first example) or a date only (second example, even the locale matters here due to month names).

For your first example (`"2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"`), a `LocalDateTime` is not a good choice because it would ignore the time zone or offset (`Z` in this case for UTC or an offset of `+00:00` hours).

For your second example (`"July 30, 2020"`), a `LocalDate` would be sufficient for parsing the `String`, but you will have to add a time and a zone / offset in order to show and convert it properly.

Use a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime` along with `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to get the zone of the device.

Here's an example for a `ZonedDateTime` including a possibility of converting from the current time zone into another (here `"Europe/Amsterdam"`, but you would obviously have to use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` then):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val first = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"
    val second = "July 30, 2020"
    // parse the first example directly to a ZonedDateTime, the String has a default format
    val firstZdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(first)
    // parse the second String using a matching formatter
    val secondDate = LocalDate.parse(second,
                                     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))
    // then add a time of day (start of day here) and the device time zone
    val secondZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(secondDate,
                                     LocalTime.MIN,
                                     ZoneId.systemDefault())
    
    // convert a given datetime with a zone to another zone
    val europeAmsterdamFirstZdt = firstZdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))
    val europeAmsterdamSecondZdt = secondZdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))
    // then print them all
    println("$firstZdt\tis $europeAmsterdamFirstZdt\tin Amsterdam")
    println("$secondZdt\tis $europeAmsterdamSecondZdt\tin Amsterdam")
}
```

output of this example code:

```
2010-10-15T09:27:37Z    is 2010-10-15T11:27:37+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]  in Amsterdam
2020-07-30T00:00Z[UTC]  is 2020-07-30T02:00+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam] in Amsterdam
```

Comment: @user1448108 You're welcome. Thanks for accepting this answer, please consider upvoting it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you'll need to check the format of the date string returned from the api matches what you expect. Because you have multiple format options you'll have to safely check this.You can do that like so:

```
val first = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"
val second = "July 30, 2020"

fun main(){
    var firstOne = getCorrectFormatFromDateString(first)
    var secondOne = getCorrectFormatFromDateString(second)
}


fun getCorrectFormatFromDateString(dateString: String): String {
    // these are the possible formats from the api
    val zonedFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    val stringDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, uuuu")
    // this is the format you want to display on your UI
    val yourDesiredFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY")
    var dateStringToReturn = ""
    try {
        // in the correct zoned date format
        val date  = zonedFormat.parse(dateString)
        dateStringToReturn = yourDesiredFormat.format(date)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        // not in the zoned format so check another format
        try {
            var date = stringDateFormat.parse(dateString)
            dateStringToReturn = yourDesiredFormat.format(date)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
           // not this format either so try another etc...
        }
    }

    return dateStringToReturn
}
```

You can set the desired format that you want and can check multiple formats via try/catch. This is only ideal if you know all the possible formats the api can return the date in.

in @deHaar's answer you can see how to correctly format to timezones but this is the safest way to check that the date if in the format you expect